# Python PyQt5 QTableView Change selected row Backgroundcolor

Tags: pyqt5, selection, qtableview

I have a QTableView with QAbstractTableModel. I want to change row backgroundcolor when I click one cell. I know at least two methods that can change row backgroundcolor when clicking one cell. One is use delegate, and another is use setData method in QAbstractTable. But I have got none of them,,,oops. Here I tried using setData method in QAbstractTable to just change the selected cell backgroundcolor, but failed! Could you pls help me to correct my code in order to change a whole row color not just a cell. Anyway, changing cell color is not even ok! Much thanks! Code below

```
import sys
import typing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QWidget, QTableView, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data:pd.DataFrame):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role==Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = str(self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()])
            return value

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value: typing.Any, role: int = ...) -> bool:
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        else:
            if role==Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [role])
                return True


    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[1]


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myTable = QTableView()
        df = self.get_DataFrame_Data()
        self.model = MyTableModel(df)
        self.myTable.setModel(self.model)
        self.myTable.clicked.connect(self.change_row_bgcolor)
        hlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.myTable)
        dummy_widget = QWidget()
        dummy_widget.setLayout(hlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(dummy_widget)
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

    def get_DataFrame_Data(self):
        ndarray = np.random.randint(10, 50, (7, 3))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=ndarray, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
        return df

    def change_row_bgcolor(self, index):
        self.model.setData(index,Qt.red,Qt.BackgroundColorRole)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Two ways to changed QTableView Row background color when user mouse clicking.

1. Use QStyledItemDelegate.
   Subclass QStyledItemDelegate. You should set a class property (etc tableview's currentindex) which can be reset value from outside the class, by this, the delegate's default loop will compare the tableview's currentindex.Code:

```
    class TableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        
        select_index = None
    
        def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: 'QStyleOptionViewItem', index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
            # option.state
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            select_row = self.select_index.row()
            # self.initStyleOption(option,index)
            if row == select_row:
                # option.font.setItalic(True)
                option.font.setStyle(QFont.StyleOblique)
                bg = QColor(135, 206, 255)
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, bg)
                # painter.eraseRect(option.rect)
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

2. Use QAbstractTableModel.Also, you should set a class property, than the method data()'s default loop will compare with the class property(tableview's current index). and set backgroud color.Code:

```
    class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
        def __init__(self, data:pd.DataFrame):
            super().__init__()
            self._data = data
            self.color_enabled = False
            self.color_back = Qt.magenta
            self.target_row = -1
    
        def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int) -> typing.Any:
            if role==Qt.DisplayRole:
                # print(index.row())
                value = str(self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()])
                return value
            if role == Qt.BackgroundRole and index.row()==self.target_row \
                    and self.color_enabled==True:
                return QBrush(self.color_back)
```

And,,! there is another special problem that should emphasized here. When user click one cell, there is a default backgroud which I see in my computer is blue.  If you want to whole row background color is same when clicking, you should do this after creating a QTableView:

```
self.myTable.setStyleSheet("QTableView::item:selected{"
                   "background:rgb(135, 206, 255)}")
```

This means,you set the selected cell bgcolor by QSS, and then, either when you use QAbstractTableModel' data() method or pain() method in QStyledItemDelege, you should set the same color. Then everything is ok!
[image]